# sequentially number a line of linked images with vim or other?

Tags: vim

I have over 400 lines of html containing this code for images:

```
<a class='gallery' href="galimages/boards/board34.jpg" alt="board large"><image src ="galimages/boards/thumbs/34.jpg" alt="board thumb"></a>
```

The first lot are board images and go from number 34 to 160.

Is there a way to programmitically number them because each line of code is identical except for the numbers?

I am on Centos 7 and I use vim editor normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Vim solution

Some suggestions [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip971). I'd create the list of numbers, then substitute the rest of the string around them. I find this strategy easier, since you'd want two of each number. For example, in an empty document:

```
:put =range(34,160)
:%s,\(.*\),<a class='gallery' href="galimages/boards/board\1.jpg" alt="board large"><image src ="galimages/boards/thumbs/\1.jpg" alt="board thumb"></a>
```

N.B. `put` creates an empty line on the first line, so you'll have to delete that manually.

#### Explanation

- `:put =range(34,160)`: Create a range of numbers from 34 to 160, one on each line. As noted, this actually starts the document with a blank line, so manually delete it now or later.
- `:%s,FOO,BAR`: Over the whole document (`%`), do a search and replace (`s`), replacing `FOO` with `BAR`.
- `FOO`: `\(.*\)`. Replace the whole line (`.*`), but store the contents (number) into a capturing group, i.e. `\(...\)` .
- `BAR`: Replace with the string as required, using the number in two places (`\1`), to create the final lines.

## Shell solution

You can use a similar strategy in the shell without using `vim`.

```
$ seq 34 160 | sed 's,\(.*\),<a class='\''gallery'\'' href="galimages/boards/board\1.jpg" alt="board large"><image src ="galimages/boards/thumbs/\1.jpg" alt="board thumb"></a>,'
```

### Explanation

- `seq 34 160`: Create a range of numbers from 34 to 160, one on each line.
- `sed…`: substitute as above. N.B. since I quote the `sed` argument with `'`, this script escapes the in-line `'`s with `'\''`.

Comment: I am having trouble following this ...

Comment: @cea Which part specifically? Did it work for you? Or are you saying you don't understand the logic? I'll post an explanation anyway.

Comment: no i'm trying still, first of all comes up with error -trailing characters if I just try the first put command

Comment: @cea I'm not sure; it works for me. Are you literally typing it or copy-pasting?

Comment: ok if i paste everything after put: it says x amount substitutions now press enter but then nothing happens- numbers are all the same

Comment: I will play around it for a while thanks and if it works for you must for me! I will return...

Comment: @cea Sorry, I'm confused. Does the first `put` line work or not? You should see a list sequential numbers, one per line.

Comment: It is creating lines with no numbers.

Comment: Thanks for further explanation - will study it and return at a later date  to award once I have working.

Comment: @cea I wonder if something in `~/.vimrc` is interfering. Can you try to launch it with `vim -u NONE /tmp/foo`, then try the `put` command again?

Comment: @cea Alternatively, you can try `:for i in range(34,160) | put =i | endfor`.

Comment: @cea I posted up an alternative in the meantime.

Comment: @cea No worries. Glad to help. No idea why the `vim` version didn't work though. Please report back if you work out why.

Comment: Yes, I will. I don't know why either- I've been too busy to sit down with it and do it carefully but I def will because it comes in very handy within the editor.thanks